# How to implement microdata? A practical guide?

Tags: cms, microdata

I've read the documentation page about upcoming Joomla 3.3 Microdata http://docs.joomla.org/Microdata

It sounds Ok.... but how can a user implement it in a simple articles-loaded-by-user site?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, Joomla 3.3 will have it hardcoded in the layout files, because it's just not easy to use by the user. There is a GSoC project to make the library more user friendly.

Comment: Is there a link or thread that describes the GSoC initiative?

Comment: There is a short project description: https://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/details/google/gsoc2014/palex/5665319561461760 and some discussion in the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/joomla-dev-general/microdata/joomla-dev-general/s0SR7hyfW_I/JiJG9yM5dE4J

Answer (score 3):

Also, JCE has included a microdata editor plugin that may be useful in the meantime.

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/documentation/107-microdata/385-creating-and-editing-microdata

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Edited to add the link to the microdata plugin for you.  It relies on the library at http://schema.rdfs.org .  I must admit I don't have a lot of clients where this has been a need until the recently